# Problem making a JProgressBar update values in Loop (Threaded)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, progress-bar, swingworker

Am trying to get my program to update the progress bar values constantly within a method while performing some operations. However this does not happen until the end, and the UI freezes.

After looking around to similar questions with my problems, I tried to implement the accepted solutions (Using threads) however I cannot get it to work correctly. Is just like if they where not there.

My program contains several classes, the `Main` being the one automatically created by netbeans on the JFrame *Design* mode, so there are certain things such as the `static void main` and the `public Main` that am not really sure of some of its contents. Under i will put the snippets of those methods, together with my thread implementation.

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable{
                                          // I added implements ActLis, Runn.....

...

static Main _this;      // I included this variable

...

public static void main(String args[]) {
        Main m = new Main();                               // Added by me
        new Thread(m).start();                             // Added by me
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
 }

...

public Main() {
        initComponents();
        _this = this;        // Added by me
}


...

// I also included these 2 methods in the class

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                                    
    synchronized(this){                                                         
        notifyAll();                                                            
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               

public void run() {                                                             
    try{synchronized(this){wait();}}
    catch (InterruptedException e){}
    progressBar.setValue(50);                                                   
}

...

private void buttonPressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
   for(int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<=5; j++) {
         // does some work
      }
   run();
   }
}
```

All the things that I commented as `I added...` are things that I putted according to tutorials and answers I have seen online, but nothing seems to work and it feels like I have tried close to a million different combinations...

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's some basis for you to look at, if you can study it and understand why every piece of code is there then I think it will help. Feel free to ask questions in a comment (although I'm going to bed right now!)

**Example:**

```
public class ProgressBarDemo extends JFrame {
    private final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    private int progressCounter = 0;

    public ProgressBarDemo() {
        setContentPane(progressBar);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressCounter <= 100) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setValue(progressCounter++);
                        }
                    });
                    try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ProgressBarDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Two different ways to approach the problem, using SwingWorker instead:

**SwingWorker Example 1:**

```
    ....
    public ProgressBarDemo() {
        setContentPane(progressBar);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();

        SwingWorker<Integer, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Integer,Void>() {
            public Integer doInBackground() {
                while (progressCounter <= 100) {
                    setProgress(progressCounter++);
                    try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
                return 0;
            }
        };
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
                if ("progress".equals(event.getPropertyName())) {
                    progressBar.setValue((Integer)event.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        });
        worker.execute();
    }
    ....
```

**SwingWorker Example 2 (not so nice, but interesting nonetheless):**

```
    ....
    public ProgressBarDemo() {
        setContentPane(progressBar);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();

        new SwingWorker<Integer,Integer>() {
            public Integer doInBackground() { 
                while (progressCounter <= 100) {
                    publish(progressCounter++);
                    try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}                    
                }
                return 0;
            }
            public void process(List<Integer> progresses) {
                Integer maxProgress = null;
                for (int progress : progresses) {
                    if (maxProgress == null || progress > maxProgress) {
                        maxProgress = progress;
                    }
                }
                progressBar.setValue(maxProgress);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
    ....
```

Comment: wow, buddy really it means a lot to me all the time and thought you have put into helping me understand threading and solving the problem. Am glad to say I have managed to do it using your first example. Where do I **triple** tick as best freaking answer?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things wrong with your code :(

- you're creating Main twice, and you end up waiting on one instance and notifying the other.
- you're manually calling run() as well as schedule a thread to do that too...

forget tutorials, write the code from scratch and only add things to it you understand.

Comment: +1 iluxa is right. Consider `SwingWorker`, as suggested in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637725).