# How to set a progress bar between two jframes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jprogressbar

I need a progressbar in between two jframes;ie while navigating from one jframe to other the progress of loading that frame must shown in a progressbar.It should also show a message like 'Please wait....'.Please help

Comment: 1) You've [already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084884/to-set-delay-on-a-button-click-in-java) been advised to use `JProgressBar` and been given some links as to how to use it with `SwingWorker`/`Timer`.  What is the specific problem?  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* effectively asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.  2) Please use the simple decency to make your post easy to read by using correct caps. for J2SE class names or alternately using the generic name.  That would be ***`JFrame` or frame.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) don't use two [JFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), use [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) instead of...,

2) better woudl be use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) rather than bunch of `JFrames` or `JDialogs`

3) you have to look at [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) (example in the tutorial)

4) invoke the code about processes in `JProgresBar` from [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) (example in the tutorial)

5) [more examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm)

Comment: For more on point 1 see [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Center using the parent container of the two frames?